# How do I remux AVC/AAC MKV into H264/AAC WTV?

Tags: video-conversion, matroska

I would like to use Windows Media Center fast forward functionality to play video at 1.5x speed.

With todvrms.exe included in DVRMSToolbox package, the conversion stucks at 99,81%.

What is the problem? Which other software could I use to perform this operation?

FFmpeg helped me but i'm unable to specify vcodec as h264 (only `avc -> mpeg2video` works).

**EDIT:**

MediaInfo of a H.264 WTV file:

```
General Complete name      : \\server\share\Recorded_Show_HD_2012_07_14_14_00_00.wtv
Format                     : AVC
Format/Info                : Advanced Video Codec
File size                  : 1.30 GiB

Video Format               : AVC / AVC
Format/Info                : Advanced Video Codec
Form at profile            : Unknown@L19.4 / High@L4.0 / High@L9.6 
MultiView_Count            : 108
Format settings, CABAC     : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames  : 4 frames / 5 frames
Width                      : 1 920 pixels / 90 pixels
Height                     : 1 080 pixels / 508 pixels
Display aspect ratio       : 0.177
Frame rate                 : 25.000 fps
Color space                : YUV / YUV
Chroma subsampling         : 4:2:0
Bit depth                  : 8 bits
Scan type                  : MBAFF / Progressive
Color primaries            : BT.709-5, BT.1361, IEC 61966-2-4, SMPTE RP177
Transfer characteristics   : BT.709-5, BT.1361
Matrix coefficients        : BT.709-5, BT.1361, IEC 61966-2-4 709, SMPTE RP177
```

ToDRVMS.exe log:

```
C:\Users\Admin>"C:\Program Files (x86)\DVRMSToolbox\Applications\todvrms.exe" "D:\Admin\Desktop\The.Big.Bang.Theory.S05E16.FRENCH.720p.LD.WEB-DL.H264-NCK.mkv" "D:\Admin\Desktop\The.Big.Bang.Theory.S05E16.FRENCH.720p.LD.WEB-DL.H264-NCK.wtv" -v -wtv
Using Haali MKV source filter
MKV Source loaded
File source set
Source filter GUID: 55da30fc-f16b-49fc-baa5-ae59fc65f82d
Find Video pin
Add AttributeEnable Filter
Connect source to AE pin
Add AVC1toH264 Filter
Connect first pin
Add VA Filter
Connect stream/video pin to mpg analyzer
Get input on SBE
Input pin obtained, connect it
Connected Analyzer pin
Grab the connected pin
Grab the connected pin
Grab the connected pin
Got audio pin
Write MetaDataItem duration = 12408800000
Write MetaDataItem wm/toolname = todvrms
Write Attributes
Start Recording
Run the graph
4,1%
7,5%
11,03%
11,95%
14,39%
16,9%
19,13%
22,04%
25,31%
28,03%
30,81%
34,55%
37,71%
40,12%
43,04%
45,28%
48,92%
52,52%
56%
57,57%
60,38%
63,89%
67,02%
70,62%
72,95%
75,62%
79,51%
83,45%
86,86%
90,57%
94,19%
97,51%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
99,6%
^C
C:\Users\Admin>
```

Comment: How long do you give it before pressing ^C? If it is like some other encoders then it may be that it encodes the audio and video separately and then multiplexes them together, on a slow hard drive this step could take a good few minutes for large files.

Comment: Rather than convert the file, why not install the components Windows Media Center needs in order to play MKV files?

Comment: @Mokubai - hours!

Comment: @Richard - Codecs are installed, but I would like to use this button: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdfQ.png

Comment: Have you tried installing Media Control Plugin? That will enable the ffwd button to be used to go at 1.5 speed. It won't, sadly, make that button work though.

Answer (score 0):

The only software I've found which can convert to and from the WTV container (h264 or mpg) is http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm.  It's not overpriced for all it can do and there's a forum in which the programmers are very active.